# Add second full length row to each mat-row in a mat-table

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table with 4-5 columns but I would like to show one other property as a 'description' under each row. I don't want to sort or filter by this property. The result should look something like this:

```
Column1       Column2        Column3
------------------------------------------------
Row1Value1    Row1Value2     Row1Value3
Row1ValueDescription that is 3 columns long
------------------------------------------------
Row2Value1    Row2Value2     Row2Value3
Row2ValueDescription that is 3 columns long
------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible with mat-table or I have to use html table instead?
I've tried to add a div into  like this but that was just overwitten by ngcontainers:

```
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: contentDisplayedColumns">
      <div>element.description</div>
   </mat-row>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do it as in [docs example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-expandable-rows). The only difference is making rows always visible. E.g. by changing `[class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"` to `[class.example-expanded-row]="true"`